# how to show/hide div according to user permission/role using angularjs in sharepoint 2010

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint-2010

i have to create a form using content editor web part in SharePoint 2010. I have to hide some item or div based on group permission (example: admin,user) using angularjs.

Comment: Please, check this **[Show and Hide section based on SharePoint Group](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-hide-div-based-user-group-in-sharepoint-via-spservices/)**

Answer (score 1):

There have two ways to solve your problem:

1. You receive all the data and you display it or not based on the current role, helped by a display function. [jsFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/gikoo/0cL4nw1y/)

   Javascript code:

   ```
   var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);
   demoApp.controller('PermissionsForm', function ($scope) {

       // Mock data. You must receive it from your server
       $scope.mockData = {
           field1: {
           value: 'field1 value',
           roles: ['admin','user']
           },
           field2: {
               value: 'field2 value',
               roles: ['admin']
           },
               field3: {
               value: 'field3 value',
               roles: ['admin','user']
           },
           role: 'user'
       };

       $scope.displayField = function(fieldName){
           var foundRole = false;
           angular.forEach($scope.mockData[fieldName].roles, function(value, key) {
               if (value == $scope.mockData.role){    
                   foundRole = true;
               }
           });
           return foundRole;
       };
   });
   ```

   HTML code:

   ```
   <div data-ng-app="demoApp" data-ng-controller="PermissionsForm" class="main">
       <form>
           <div ng-if="displayField('field1')">
               <label for="field1">Field 1</label>
               <input id="field1" value="{{mockData.field1.value}}">
           </div>
           <div ng-if="displayField('field2')">
               <label for="field2">Field 2</label>
               <input id="field2"value="{{mockData.field2.value}}">
           </div>
           <div ng-if="displayField('field3')">
               <label for="field3">Field 3</label>
               <input id="field3"  value="{{mockData.field3.value}}">
           </div>
       </form>
   </div>
   ```
2. You receive only the data related to each roles/permission and you build your interface with the list of fields. This is the more secure way to hide info. [jsFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/gikoo/ob5atma1/)

   Javascript code:

   ```
   var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);
   demoApp.controller('PermissionsForm', function ($scope) {

       // Mock data. You must receive it from your server
       $scope.mockData = {
           field1: {
               value: 'field1 value'
           },
           field3: {
               value: 'field3 value'
           },
           field4: {
               value: 'field4 value'
           }
       };


       $scope.displayField = function(fieldName){
           if ( $scope.mockData[fieldName] == undefined )
               return false;
           return true;
       };
   });
   ```

   HTML code:

   ```
   <div data-ng-app="demoApp" data-ng-controller="PermissionsForm" class="main">
       <form>
           <div ng-if="displayField('field1')">
               <label for="field1">Field 1</label>
               <input id="field1" value="{{mockData.field1.value}}">
           </div>
           <div ng-if="displayField('field2')">
               <label for="field2">Field 2</label>
               <input id="field2"value="{{mockData.field2.value}}">
           </div>
           <div ng-if="displayField('field3')">
               <label for="field3">Field 3</label>
               <input id="field3"  value="{{mockData.field3.value}}">
           </div>
           <div ng-if="displayField('field4')">
               <label for="field4">Field 4</label>
               <input id="field4"  value="{{mockData.field4.value}}">
           </div>
       </form>
   </div>
   ```

From a secure point of view, the second solution is the best, because your are not exposing the data in the client side (browser)

Comment: var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);
demoApp.controller('PermissionsForm', function ($scope) {

    // Mock data. You must receive it from your server
    $scope.mockData = {
        field1: {
        value: 'field1 value',
        roles: ['admin']
        },
        field2: {
            value: 'field2 value',
            roles: ['user']
        },
        role: 'user'   
        
    };
when I am giving role: 'user' then both user and admin see the field value2 and vice versa??

Comment: As you configure your mock, only 'user' can see field2. If you set the active role to 'admin', he will see only the field 1.
If you want the field2 visible for both, put 'admin' and 'user' in roles array of field2

Comment: Note that in jsFiddle, once you update the code you need to rerun it by pressing RUN button in the top bar ;)